# How to get the reference of an opened window with target blank

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the reference by javascript of a window that it's open after clicking an ANCHOR that has a target _blank.

Like this:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">
new window
</a>
```

So I can check if later if the window was closed.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: I'm too lazy to check, but try using a custom target value (like target="foo"). That should open a new window named "foo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<a href="..." target="_blank" id="my-link">
new window
</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var link = document.getElementById('my-link');

link.onclick = function() {
    var reference = window.open(link.href, '_blank');
    return false;
}
```

[See it!](http://jsfiddle.net/wBJA8/)

If you simply wanted all links with `target="_blank"`, this should succeed in selecting them.

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    blankLinks = [];

for (var i = 0, linksLength = allLinks.length; i < linksLength; i++) {

    if (allLinks[i].getAttribute('target') === '_blank') {
        blankLinks.push(allLinks[i]);
    }

}
```

On a fresh browser...

```
var blankLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]);
```

Comment: I miss to mention that window.open in most broswer gets blocked by the browser, but if you use target blank it won't.

Comment: var reference = window.open(link.href, '_blank'); This should be the way to go but like I said it gets blocked by most browsers.

Comment: @Giancarlo Corzo Check the example. It is not blocked for me. I use `window.open()` all the time (fired from click events) and have no issues.

Comment: It seems that window.open is blocked as a popup if you resize the new window. If you leave it alone and just give it a url and reference it won't be blocked. At least not with Chrome 16 and Firefox 10 where I just tested.

Comment: Is it really necessary to set the window name to `'_blank'`?

Comment: @pushkin It's the name to open always a new window, otherwise you can re-use other 'named' windows